# how to use pre-trained word embeddings in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, word-embedding

I wanted to experiment with word embeddings and create models making use of them. But I am struggling to find a library/model to use? What is the quickest way to have word embeddings and use them in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Google's World2Vec pretrained model. Check out the documentations here https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#module-gensim.models.word2vec, specifically the "Pretrained models" section.